# flash shared object is not working across multiple PCs

Tags: browser, shared-objects

I am using SharedObject to save some persistent information (such as visited slide, etc) on user browser. For example, if user visited the slide, it will highlight the button that takes them to that slide. If they close the browser, and revisited the website, that button will still be highlighted. It worked out well on my laptop. But when I sent out for testing to my 3 co-workers. Two of them were having problems with it. The other one has no problem at all.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the timing when the sharedobject is saved.

In order for it to work properly, when you have set the sharedObject value it should be stored right away. You can do this by calling the `flush()` function from the SharedObject. This will make sure that it save right away instead of waiting to be saved in the queue.